Intuition for formula of 2D - divergence
I pretty much understand most of the formula except for one part. What the model is in my brain after scouring the internet is that divergence is imagining infinite amount of vectors representing movement of an object entering an infinitely small volume of dx and dy and an infinite amount of possible vectors flowing out of the point at infinite directions, representing what the possible positions of the object after entering the point. Positive divergence mean vector magnitude gets larger and negative divergence mean magnitude gets smaller. However, I was imagining a, for example, function with a vector (50,20) entering the point with:
$$ \frac {\partial P}{dx} = -1\:, \frac {\partial Q}{dy} = 2 $$
and imagine this derivative stays constant for at least a one unit change in x and a one unit change in y. According to the formula which is:
$$ div \: \vec{v} (x,y) = \frac {\partial P}{dx} +\frac {\partial Q}{dy}$$
the divergence should be positive. However, in my model, a one unit change in x and a one unit change in y will cause the magnitude of the vector to shrink. In my model, I presume that the magnitude of the vector will need to increase if it is a positive divergence. So, what's wrong with my logic?
P.S. I have only learn this topic online and haven't gone through the limit definition of divergence. Please try (as best as you can) to avoid mentioning this definition in your explanation.

You may also be interested in browsing questions about the intuition behind divergence, as in this search: https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bmultivariable-calculus%5d%20divergence%20intuition%20is%3aq&searchOn=3


Positive divergence mean vector magnitude gets larger and negative divergence mean magnitude gets smaller.

This is your misconception. Positive divergence basically means more total vector components (at some fixed distance) pointing away than pointing inward. To use your example: if $\langle P,Q\rangle$ is a differentiable vector field with $\frac {\partial P}{dx} = -1\:, \frac {\partial Q}{dy} = 2$ at some point and $\frac {\partial P}{dy} = 0\:, \frac {\partial Q}{dx} = 0$ at the same point, then around a small blue circle near a point where $\langle P,Q\rangle=\langle 50,20\rangle$, the vector field would look as in the image below (vector lengths scaled for illustration).
It's true that the lengths of the (solid black) vectors on the right side (e.g. the one in the upper right you discussed) are smaller than the length of the $\langle 50,20\rangle$ vector at the center. But what actually matters is essentially that the total of the lengths of the (dashed orange) components pointing away from the center is greater than the total of the lengths of the (dashed orange) components pointing towards the center, signifying positive divergence.


Thank you so much for the info!

@bananasaregood Happy to help! If this satisfied your question, you can signify that by clicking the checkmark.

After thinking about it for a few days, I understood your point, but I don't get how this makes the formula correct for divergence correct. I know now that my understanding was flawed, but how this new model makes the divergence formula correct?
